# detect phone call finished while running music in IOS

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am playing a radio on my app. When someone calls me during playing the radio, the radio gets muted and its fine but the problem is i want to play the music automatically after finishing the call. How can i detect the calling finished? Is it possible at all? I am using AvPlayer to play, pause. Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491047/delegate-to-know-when-phone-call-ends-which-was-initiated-by-app)
`CoreTelephony` framework has a `CTCallCenter` Class with `callEventHandler` property.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^callEventHandler)(CTCall*);
```

You will have to define a handler block in your application and assign it to this property. If your application is active when a call event takes place, the system dispatches the event to your handler immediately when call state changes.